# function donot execute for first time in jquery

Tags: jquery

Thi function donot execute for first time . Can you please help me . i am using jquery-2.0.3.js

```
 function fillnum(sender) {

 $(document).ready(function () {
var id = $(sender).attr('id');

$('#' + id).keydown(function (event) {
    if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)) {  return false;  }
    else { return true; }
});

});
```

}

Comment: How do you call the function and how do you define sender?

Comment: Your function should be inside your document.ready

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fillnum(sender) {
        var id = $(sender).attr('id');
        $('#' + id).keydown(function(event) {
            if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: That would create a function when the document is ready. It would not run it. It would not set up a listener for keydown. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @LeeMeador, my question nr 1 on the comments is "How do you call the function and how do you define sender?", but the OP needs to change this to start width.

Comment: The more pertinent issue would be that `fillnum` is now within a different scope, and is probably out of scope for whatever it is that is calling it ?

Comment: @adeneo, true. I wait for OP input on some questions we posed before changing answer more, meanwhile I look at your answer and learn with it :)

Answer (score 0):

Normally this wouldn't be in a function but you do have to define `sender` first:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var id = $(sender).attr('id');

  $('#' + id).keydown(function (event) {
    if ((event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57)) {  return false;  }
    else { return true; }
  });

});
```

The code in the function only gets executed when the function is called. Having the above in the function means that no listener/handler for 'on load' gets set up until the function is called elsewhere.

Sometimes code is in a function to isolate it but you will need to call it immediately in that case:

```
function fillnum(sender) {
    ... whatever ...
}

fillnum(sender);
```

Or even if you don't need a name:

```
function(sender) {
    ... whatever ...
}(sender);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just write the function like this, and make sure you don't call it before the DOM is ready :

```
function fillnum(sender) {
    $('#' + sender.id).on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```